# Can we raise the bar for reputation for late answers to bypass the review queue?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, late-answers

I would like to raise the bar for **late answers** to enter the **Late Answers Review Queue** to 50 rep, which is the threshold after which users gain the ability **to comment**. Here are some answers that were posted by users with between 10 to 50 rep (yes, there's a little selection bias to be sure. I suspect most/all of these will be 10k links only by the time you're reading this. Note, all of these are from the **last 5 hours.**

These are all from Stack Overflow, where I have the most experience, but since Late Answers have a much higher probability to be bad *across all stacks*, I think this applies generally. Also, I have bolded all the users references to the inability to comment, that were not in their original answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32702471/1768232 (23 rep)

  > Solution provide by @brandonyang works for me too! (**I can't add comments in a response 'cause my low reputation, sorry**).
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32703040/1768232 (47 rep)

  > I tried your answer but it doesn't work in office 365 outlook online. Do you have any suggestions?
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32701373/1768232 (26 rep)

  > My question is somehow related to the same issue. I am fairly new to C# and have been doing JAVA for quite a long time. When I am coding in C# with .Net framework 4.5.1 using visual studio 2013, I get errors for using certain libraries but I donot know which dll should I reference in my project How do C# people figure that out? For example I wanted to code to draw an ellipse and needed system.Windows.Media and System.Windows.Controls both of which were giving me errors, after googling for quite sometime I got to know that we need to reference PresentationFramework.dll, is this the only way to figure it out?
  >
  > PS >> **I am unable to post this as a comment hence putting it as answer.**
  >
  > Thanks.
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32699722/1768232 (19 rep)

  > i like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dgzOwuoXVJU&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE&index=2) video. It explains the differences between int and Integer and cautions of using Integer
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32698255/1768232 (21 rep)

  > I have a question, i am actually trying to copy the database from Prod server to test server ( SQL server 2008R2). I am wondering would it copy the users logins, roles and permission as well ?

---

I know I suggested 50 rep above, but while I was compiling that, I [found one from a 61 rep user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32699851/1768232). Perhaps it should be 100 rep, not 50. I am less confident about this, but I thought I'd add it as an addendum for discussion.

> The answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32397808/2437881) is the simplest solution that you are looking for to solve your problem, so take a look ;)

Comment: 50 rep is okay. Don't raise it too much or the queue will get flooded.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I definitely want 50, because of the comment privilege threshold. 100 I'm less sure about.

Comment: @pat The late answer queue, at least on SO, doesn't get many reviews at all. I think it only takes 1 review too to complete the review. So definitely don't see a problem increasing reviews there. I also have a [feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276078/thirty-days-late-is-extremely-late-in-internet-time) to increase reviews of late answers.

Comment: @CRABOLO That's a good request. I also have a request to [increase the number of eyeballs needed to dismiss a post as no-action needed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266027/make-three-no-action-needed-required-to-remove-something-from-first-posts-and)

Comment: @CRABOLO: On ELL, RPG, and SX the late answers queue is one of the hardest to ever find any reviews in at all (second only to reopen). I think we can confidently state that LA is not presently at risk of being flooded on most (all?) sites, even with a substantial bump in volume.

Comment: AHAHA thanks for 40 reviews. ;)

Comment: @Nathan don't worry about ELL though, the chat has two avid reviewers and me. I think sites can hold this off in chat pretty well.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M: My entire first page of rep dropdown is downvotes I just cast on late answers. It's great.

Comment: I dunno, this is hard to gauge. Maybe we'll have t'wait-it-out.  I didn't see truly convincing hard data to make such a change. A bit on anecdotal side, to pull arbitrary answers. But.. good intent

Comment: @Adel: Judging by the inflation in most sites' LQP queues that I've seen, it seems there was a fair need for this. That plus the up/down-votes is a pretty good justification. The SF/SU review flooding was a surprise, though.

Comment: It is getting tiresome that the standard solution to quality problems on the site(s) is always "more reviews". Instead of demanding quality from new users _before_ their post is even uploaded to the site, people keep insisting on reviewing existing posts and look for crap. Block the crap from entering the site in the first place! For example, block every short answer that contains a question mark at the end of a sentence.

Comment: People are posting comments as answers, because they are not allowed to comment. Instead of allowing them to comment, we're now creating extra review work and still the users are not able to comment, although some of the example comments were helpful. How about fixing the problem instead of the symptoms?

Comment: _"I can't add comments in a response 'cause my low reputation, sorry"_ Oh man I fscking HATE that. What neurological catastrophe has led these people to think that _bypassing the restriction by doing a bad thing_ is appropriate/okay/acceptable??! Do they not spend even a microsecond determining _why_ the reputation limit was there in the first place? It's not a leap from that to the conclusion "oh, okay, _I shouldn't post this_." saiduhfaklsiudfa

Comment: @Chris many of the sort of NAAs this captures also wouldn't make good comments either, such as the first example.

Comment: @Lighness To me as a layman the current rules appear as a privilege inversion. The more serious and consequential action -- answering -- requires less reputation than the rather inconsequential and easy-to-delete or -ignore  comment. Of course the users contribute (in their opinion: help) in the way that's open to them. Not the users are illogical, but the rules are. Perhaps new users should gain reputation from upvoted comments before they are allowed to answer... or at least be able to comment right away as well.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Could be because there's not really any sound rationale why someone would be allowed to post an answer but not a comment, while we at the same time have much higher expectations of the quality of an answer than on the quality of a comment. I believe the only reason behind the 50 rep rule was to dodge outright spammers. So it actually has nothing to do with "only experienced users can be trusted with the privilege to comment".

Comment: @Lundin: Perhaps. Though arguably the subsequent behaviour of these users really only shows that they can't be trusted with the privilege to answer, either.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Indeed, so the solution would either be to manually review every new user's post (extremely tedious), or implement smarter scripts that checks the answer before it is allowed to enter the site.

Comment: @Lundin Or, option 3: crowd source reviewing people's answers so that every interested user only reviews, say, at most 20 answers per day that these answers are decent.

Comment: @Lundin: Huh...?

Comment: @durron597 That's what I just said. Extremely tedious. I believe you need 500+ rep to get access to review queues. How many crap posts by new users do you think there are for every 500+ rep user? And how many crap posts are there per 500+ rep user who is willing to do reviews? And then remove the robo-reviewers from the equation: how much crap per 500+ rep user who is willing to do reviews and also actually does a good job reviewing? Stack Overflow lets in astronomic amounts of crap 24 hours a day. Reviews is not a viable solution.

Comment: @Lundin Stack Overflow demolished the 1.2k late answer reviews this generated in less than two hours. Fortunately, we know from [the reputation leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) how many users on SO have 500+ rep... 150,000 people. This change adjusted the late answer queue from generating 600 per day to something like 800. This means that just 10 out of those 150,000 need to do the max reviews to clear the queue now. I think your [Fermi estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem) skills are a bit off.

Comment: @durron597 I'm talking about the core problem, which is the total amount of crap produced by low rep users, not just what ends up in the late reviews queue, which is quite minimal in comparison.

Comment: @Lundin Perhaps you should be commenting and answering on [this other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer) instead of talking about an unrelated topic on this question, then.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: I know it looks backwards on the surface, but I think requiring 50 reputation to comment has saved us from having to deal with all sorts of trouble that other sites have with their comments. It's also critical that people learn right from the start that participation on the sites requires asking and answering, not commenting. That said, I'm actively working on [a system to let new users comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/262292/1438) if they have a mentor to help them learn to use the site. A goal of this queue is to help people earn the reputation necessary to comment.

Comment: Is the title here backwards? Isn't this the bar for reputation for late answers to *bypass* (not enter) the review queue?

Comment: @Chris I'm fully on your side. For an absolute SO/SE beginner, it can be a steep road to gain the 50 rep to comment (I know what I had to go through myself, as 95% of questions were already asked, so it wouldn't have made sense to create a duplicate just because of the desperate hunt for reputation). __25 rep__ to comment would really be much better, and keep users from putting comments into answers because of desperation (see above once again). Ah, and please don't start with your silly "you can gain 50 rep in nooo time" rubbish again, thanks. I can't stand listening to it any more.

Comment: @syntaxerror Sorry for the late reaction, but I think the reason of the rep 50 limit is exactly this, and it is agreeable. The site says with it: "first show some work, chit-chat later". The best attractive point of the SE that you can get HQ answers to your questions; this is why we should want any newcomers to show his productivity by writing answers.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

> **TL;DR:** As of today (September 29, 2015) the maximum reputation for having an author's late answer enqueued has been raised from 10 to 50.

As for further increase to 100:

## Queue growth

Review queues lose effectiveness if posts aren't regularly (and accurately) cleared. A queue such as [close votes on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251489/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue) that never seems to get to 0 fails to provide time-sensitive feedback that aids learning. So if we raise the bar for late answers which increases the number of tasks going into the queue, we risk making the queue less useful for people answering questions late.

As I write, the Late Answer queue on Stack Overflow is empty. In the last 24 hours the number (non-audit) review tasks of each type added to the queues:

```
Review Tasks Type           
------------ ----------------- 
2467         Triage            
2428         First Post        
2333         Close Votes       
1846         Suggested Edit    
 883         Low Quality Posts 
 619         Late Answer       
 594         Helper            
 141         Reopen Vote
```

These two factors suggest that there's room to add more tasks to the Late Answer queue. Assuming we raised the reputation limit to 100, we'd add about 300 tasks:

```
Rep Bin Tasks 
------- ----- 
 10       417   
 20       160   
 30        85    
 40        76    
 50        44    
 60        41    
 70        37    
 80        21    
 90        20    
100        20
```

You might expect the number of tasks associated with the 1 to 10 reputation bin would equal the number of late answer tasks in the last day. The discrepancy stems from reputation earned since answers were added to the queue. But the takeaway is that raising the reputation limit to 100 would add half again as much work to the queue. That doesn't seem particularly onerous.

Not surprisingly, Stack Overflow would see the most added Late Answer reviews by far. Other large sites, such as Ubuntu, Server Fault, Super User and Mathematics, would get 10 or so extra reviews a day.

### Justifying 100 rather than 50 reputation

Discovering answers as comments certainly would suggest 50 as a good limit for this queue. But this queue is as much about granting exposure to potentially upvote-worthy answers as it is about finding problems. Especially on large sites, it's pretty easy for a good answer to a very old question to be lost in the noise. As a [strategy for new users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/304135/1438) answering old questions that already have good, but not excellent, answers seems productive if not that few people will notice those answers. At 10 reputation, a knowledgeable new user has one shot at earning upvotes from excellent answers to aged questions.

### A potential complication

The one concern I have is that answers are dequeued once the author has reached 100 reputation. If we raise the maximum reputation for going into the queue, we should also raise the minimum for coming out of it. Unfortunately, I don't have an easy way to gather numbers to set an appropriate level. One of the reasons I'm only looking back a day in the numbers I showed above is that it minimizes the effect of gained reputation. It's possible, but messy to estimate reputation at the time a user answered a question. So while my instinct would be to raise the deque minimum to 200, but I can't really predict if that's appropriate or not.

## Resolution

Raising the bar to 100 would require changing two variables at once. Since that would make it harder to evaluate each individual change, I raised the reputation for getting a Late Answer enqueued to 50. I will reconsider upping it to 100 at some point in the future. (Hopefully we can do it in a less [jarring manner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267081/why-did-the-late-answer-queue-spike-on-sep-29-2015), however.)

Comment: You make an excellent point about giving extra scrutiny to good answers from new users, that I hadn't considered! One question though, it seems as though most of your answer was arguing in favor of making it go to 100 (since 50% more tasks isn't particularly onerous), but then you concluded to raise it to only 50. Could you explain why?

Comment: @durron597: I edited the concluding section. Basically, going to 50 with an option to 100 relieves me of trying to set a limit for dequeuing without any data.

Comment: **Are you sure you want thousands of old answers to enter the queue now?** Are you sure that _all sites_ profit from an increased threshold?

Comment: @JonEricson: One on C.SE from [2013](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24403864#24403864) and one on PPCG from [2011](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24403905#24403905). A month, eh?

Comment: @JonEricson We've got hundreds of posts with "active: 2 years ago". Are you should about "answers should not be older than a month"? I smell a bug here... :D

Comment: @El'endiaStarman: Looks like this is the second time in as many weeks as you've caught me making bad assumptions about how things work around here. ;-) Well, now's the time to earn that Late Answer Reviewer badge you've always wanted.

Comment: @JonEricson One can make at most 20 a day, so no luck :-)

Comment: @yo' Except that I happen to be a mod on a site...so reviews would be unlimited for me.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman Cheater! :D

Comment: Please roll back this change immediately. We have now a 3.2k entries long review queue on ServerFault. That's total crap.

Comment: @Sven Give it a couple days, it will clean up.

Comment: @yo': If I didn't miss some thing in this answer that will clean this queue up automatically, it will not clear up on SF.  We don't have many reviewers to begin with and many (including me) have stopped to review because of the entirely braindead review audit crap.

Comment: @JonEricson [4k+ posts](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14469/158442) is a lot to review.

Comment: @muru: I'm sorry about that. Thank goodness I didn't raise the limit to 100. As a reminder, it's easier to clear a task from this queue than many others. A single review dequeues.

Comment: @Sven: Reverting won't help, I'm afraid. The damage has been done. I have gone over to pitch in on Server Fault as an act of penitence.

Comment: This as also got Arqade queue to grow a lot for the site's size, 1.5k there will be a long queue to empty. Is there any way to help with this by giving members that can review a higher review count for some time?

Comment: @JonEricson that's not enough, you know. A lot of those answers will get flagged VLQ, and then the low-quality review queue will balloon.

Comment: @Sven It really won't take that long, I'm sure it will be gone in less than 2 weeks naturally.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau: I just did a bunch of reviews on Server Fault. My most frequent action on the Late Answer queue turns out to be voting (up or down). Unfortunately, I hit the vote limit. So even if we gave more reviews temporarily, there are other limits that will slow you down. At the point, the best bet is to chip away at it for a few weeks. I apologize for the annoyance. :-(

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly is already done, and what is still planned? As it stands, the question got [tag:status-completed], but I find it hard to understand what is completed exactly.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Sure. The only thing I did today was raise the maximum reputation for having an author's late answer enqueued from 10 to 50. A further increase to 100 is possible, but that would also require changing the limit for dequeuing from 100 to... something north of that. I will also need to wait for the current spike to dissipate and the queues to return to some sort of normal. I'd also want to at least consider rate limiting the answers added to the queue.

Comment: Thanks @Jon, edited the post to clarify, hope I didn't get something wrong.

Comment: I just spotted this after posting a bug report on Arduino SE. Suddenly a whole lot of posts which were 8 months old needed review because they were a "new user's answer to an old question". Hardly new, eh, if they have been around for 8 months?

Comment: @NickGammon: Yeah. That was unplanned. However, the other way to think of it is that these users are not new in the "fresh" or "recent" sense, but in the "unseasoned" or "untried" sense. Alternatively, my excessive use of quotes might be seen as an example of "spin". ;-)

Comment: In our case it only added "about 20" to the review queue, so now I know it isn't a bug I can calmly "review" them. (Using quotes is more "fun" than I originally thought!).

Comment: This explains why the Late Answers on Raspberry suddenly jumped to 102! As a result I probably will stop reviewing this. The most common response I have to Late Answers is to recommend deletion. Unfortunately the only easily accessible options are "No action needed" and "skip"

Comment: @Milliways - you're thinking of the 'Low Quality' queue :-). Also your other options include voting (up or down), flagging, commenting or editing

Comment: @Jon Perhaps you'd like to pitch in on ELU's as well? That's now at 800+ where it was nearer single figures before. Please **do not** increase the threshold to 100 (or at least, make sure there is a real date threshold as well so old answers are not resurrected).

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I looked and I'm afraid I don't clearly understand what makes for a good answer on English.

Comment: Hmm... How about writing a patch which removes posts from the review queue where they are more than a month old?

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Since the queue on ELU has already dropped from 900 to 800 in a half day, I expect the emergency will be over before such a change could be rolled out.

Comment: Right now I expect SF's "long" review queue to be cleared in a few days, not a few weeks.

Comment: Because of the failure to restrict this to a month a temporary rename to "Late Review" queue would have been appropriate. FYI the 700+ or so extra reviews on U&L have already been cleared within less than 24 hrs

Comment: @Anthon As noted, this is a temporary thing. While a mistake has happened, I agree with Jon Ericson that it's nothing dramatic, it seems to be clearing within at most days; much faster on smaller sites. IMHO any more changes based on the current situation would be unwise.

Comment: @yo' You missed the intended pun

Comment: @JonEricson Re: Jarring: If we do this again (to 100 rep), we should make sure that the queue doesn't add tasks that are on closed questions, most of the ones I'm seeing on Programmers.SE are to closed questions, seems silly to review an answer to a bad question.

Comment: I wondered why the review queue was so large this morning on DSP.SE.  We have very few reviews, so it wasn't a big deal... still, it's interesting that it had such a big effect.

Comment: @durron597: One of the mods suggested ratcheting the threshold up in increments instead of jumping straight to the final number. Exempting closed questions is an interesting idea. On ordinary days, this rarely is an issue because it's not possible to late answer a question after it's been closed. This will only be relevant when we are adding more review tasks, which hardly ever happens. In any case, it'll probably be several months before anything else will change.

Comment: @JonEricson Agree completely; that's why I said it's only relevant to the jarring nature this time around. Still, the largest queue (SuperUser) has already reviewed 800 of the 6100; I'm beginning to think that all the queues will be back to normal by a week from the time this was first implemented.

Comment: "Assuming we raised the reputation limit to 100, we'd add about 300 tasks" – not sure if you mean "from 10" or "from 50" but either way, this statement doesn't seem to correspond to the numbers in the table that follows. I count 365 tasks in the 20, 30, 40, 50 bins and 139 tasks above 50.

Comment: @Air: I counted all the tasks in all the bin and subtracted 619, the number of tasks actually added in the same time period. People have the annoying habit of earning rep after their answers are added to this queue. ;-) It's still probably wrong since it's possible people could earn more than 100 reputation and be excluded from the second query.

Comment: I am shocked! Why did you do this change so rapidly and almost overnight? **On [ubuntu.se], we have 3700 late answer reviews now!** Who shall ever check them all? You could have raised the limit slower, in steps by 10 or 20 points for example. Can we at least have kind of a clean-up event then where people get infinite votes and flags and no maximum reviews per day limit until that humongous load of reviews has melt down again?

Comment: It were more than 4400 review items in the beginning: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14469/367990

Comment: @ByteCommander After 24 hours you've reviewed almost 1000 of them. At that rate they will be gone before next Monday. It was a mistake but I don't really see the problem.

Comment: @Jon We appear to be getting anomalous entries into the LA queue in ELU. (See [relevant comments](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/is-this-mitchs-fault/7185?noredirect=1#comment28306_7185)) Could you explain or point to an explanation of exactly how this is working, please?

Comment: @AndrewLeach you might be experiencing the thing I saw with a [late late answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213020/213963) awhile back.  A deleted post or down vote could trigger it going into the review queue if it hadn't been reviewed before.

Comment: Haha, once again a typical politician's decision. Making the decision first, and then realizing the bad impact because they made their decisions with doors closed without being patient enough to ask the people who will be doomed to deal with that oh-so-important change for the times to come. If only you had left things as they are!!

Comment: The queue on [sf] is cleared. As I said, days not weeks.

Answer (score 39):

I think this is a good idea. I spend a lot of time on the [New Answers to Questions More Than 30 Days Old list on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) (10k link), and I would agree that many of the questions I flag as not an answer are from new users who want to comment, find they don't have the privilege, and leave an answer instead.

The main concern I would have about the proposal would be whether this would overload the Late Answers Queue. To analyze that for Stack Overflow, I've looked through the 200 most recent late answers on the site. Here is the breakdown by reputation of the poster:

- 45 (23%) were from users with reputation 1-10
- 46 (23%) were from users with reputation 11-50
- 10 (5%) were from users with reputation 51-100
- 99 (50%) were from users with reputation 101+

From this limited dataset, it seems like we might see roughly a doubling of the number of answers added to the Late Answers Queue by increasing the reputation limit to 50. Increasing to 100 would not add too many more late answers to the queue. Given that the Late Answers Queue is often empty on Stack Overflow, I don't think this would be too problematic.

To get a sense of the users who are creating problematic late answers, I reviewed my most recent 200 helpful flags on late answers on Stack Overflow. Here is the breakdown by reputation:

- 132 (66%) were from users with reputation 1-10
- 39 (20%) were from users with reputation 11-50
- 10 (5%) were from users with reputation 51-100
- 19 (10%) were from users with reputation 101+

This suggests that users with reputation 1-10 are generating much more than their fair share of problematic late answers, users with reputation 101+ are generating much less than their fair share, and users with reputation 11-100 are generating about their fair share. I think this could mean that reviewing late answers for users with up to 100 reputation could make sense, but there would be diminishing returns raising the bar above 100 reputation.

It would be helpful to see this analysis repeated on other sites to see if the results are qualitatively similar ([it sounds like](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue#comment865308_266696) the relatively small size of the Late Answers Queue may hold across other sites).

Comment: Bear in mind that a lot of people use SEDE to look for questions worth flagging and low-rep users are an obvious place to start any query. This may introduce significant bias when considering helpful flags by rep range

Comment: @Basic For sure! In this answer I limited to my most recent 200 helpful flags that I had generated from the "New Answers to Questions More than 30 Days Old" list on Stack Overflow, so the results I quote about helpful flags aren't biased in the way you describe. Of course others might flag different questions than I would when reading the list, so that part of my answer is meant more to give a sense of the number of problematic late answers generated by different rep groups than to be an authoritative breakdown.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps letting people comment sooner would also be a way to solve this problem.
Note that many of the cases cited here are people w/o the rep to comment.  Creating a situation where they are thus "forced" to post an answer that isn't an answer is actually not a good thing.  It violates the "truth in packaging" idea; makes the user (presumably usually new) feel bad about the whole site, and invites others to criticize their posting an answer that is not an answer, thus cycling the whole thing downwards... being a new user on SO is not easy (and I happen to be a PhD who had about 15 years of industry experience when I started using!)

Comment: People who want to comment, but can't have to post their two-cents as answers?  How is that a good thing?

Comment: Anyone can ask or answer a question. Commenting is a privilege gained by users who have proven that they are able to contribute, and I think it should remain that way. Did *you* feel bad about the whole site? Did *you* fall into a spiral of despair when you realized you could not comment? I didn't when I was new. I was ecstatic about the fake internet points I was gaining by helping people with Java questions.

Comment: I've also commented when asking for clarification on someone else's question/answer. In this case, it would be inappropriate to ask an entirely new question, but that is the only option for someone without enough rep to comment.

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox, there are actually three options: (1) leave a comment as an answer (**this is wrong**), (2) do nothing, (3) get the reputation properly by either answering or asking a question and then comment...

Comment: @JosephDoggie: I'd recommend posting a new question with a fuller proposal for allowing comments at lower rep without being flooded by users commenting that have no idea what they're supposed to use those for. This is really just for *handling* problematic answers, and simply allowing comments won't fully solve those.

Comment: I think it's actually exactly the opposite, and is "truth in packaging" in a good way. The new user learns that this isn't a regular chit-chatty web forum and that the expected patterns of discussion fit into specific conventions.