# A "what's new" or "this just changed" notification on review page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications

If possible, could we add just a simple message/note/tag to the review queue to indicate that something has changed? Preferably with a link to the rationale/description.

For instance, I logged into my account yesterday and noticed a large amount of late answer reviews. I did my part and reviewed 20 of the several hundred. I was obviously curious as to why there was this sudden spike. Personally, I thought it was a glitch because the answers were mostly good quality and the reputation of the posters were over not novices. I was confused.

For those of you that do not know, the increase in queue size was related to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue) proposal. I believe that if there was a notification (in the message box for instance) that my confusion would have been quickly alleviated. Additionally, as I understand it, some sites are still having issues clearing this enlarged queue and so perhaps adding a notification would actually help encourage users to go [back] to the review queue and help out.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is necessary because normally posts that announce big changes to something on the SE platform are made [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) by one of the SE employees.

This adds a message to the sidebar of every SE site for people to follow and find out more:

> [image] on [Super User](http://superuser.com)

Adding a new feature for this would be useless I think because the featuree already exists, in a slightly different way.

Comment: I see what you are saying but this 'featured on meta' is often times overlooked and in any case, this particular post was 'featured' some time after the change was made.

Comment: @MatthewPeters I don't think *anything* will stop stuff from being overlooked.. :P And as for the delay - I'm sure that would happen if there was a separate message somewhere, after all: someone will always have to manually add a message *manually* - it seems easier to just edit to add [tag:featured]...