# How to behave when there is a database error or a bug on the site?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

Looking on *SuperUser* [review page](https://superuser.com/review) today I found 5.5K *late answer* waiting to be done...

I suspected a bug since, at moment, *SuperUser* site counts around 284k questions and I see not probable that 5.5K of *late answers* are arrived in one day.
Moreover checking with one, it comes out that are actually old posts (made years ago) and not a new ones.

[image: review to do]

On the same time in the statistics panel it is not congruent with the number of performed tasks that it seems me that I've done.

[image: panel statistic]

**The suspect of a database problem or a bug arises..**.
**Which is the proper behaviour to follow in this case?**

Comment: The first part is not a bug, it's because of this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue I'm not quite sure what your problem is in the second part.

Comment: @RobertLongson: thanks for the link. Is that retroactive? Because SU (284 Questions) is not stackexchange (), and 5.5k answers cannot be arrived in the last day. What about the score in the reviewer badge (I'm quite confident I've done more then 13 before yesterday)?  What about score of `381/300` for civic duty badge?

Comment: Yes, when activated it applied to all posts by users with <= 50 rep no matter how old. As to 381/300. You need 300 to get the badge, you currently have 381 so you have the badge.

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't know if it was so before. I understand that 381>300,  but I expect to see the `Electorate` one instead of the `Civic Duty` one. Does this modification applies (spreads its effects) to the badge counters too?

Comment: Electorate is not considered a successor badge to Civic Duty. Electorate requires voting on questions, Civic Duty does not.

Comment: Thanks again @RobertLongson. I supposed it was because they belong to the same category: Moderation Badges (but I see they are not grouped together).

Answer (score 7):

[We changed how the Late Answers queue is populated yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue), which did cause the queues across the network to grow.

I'm not sure what bug you're reporting in the second part of your post, though. Please edit your question to clarify what you expected to see vs what you saw. (Better yet, ask it separately since it's a different issue from the queue size).

In terms of what to do when you find a bug, the answer is "do what you just did - post on meta". :)

Comment: Thanks Anna. Robert explain me that it is retroactive. Maybe in that way it involves the counters too. I will split the questions (here I report just because it was my path to suspect a bug or db change).