# What happens when a late answer is upvoted?

Tags: support, reputation, review, late-answers

I have a doubt concerning the way the Late Answers review queue works. Suppose that, at the moment that an answer is posted, it qualifies to be sent to the Late Answers review queue. That is (please correct me if I am wrong), the poster's reputation is below or equal to 50 points and the question was posted more than 30 days ago. But then (before it was sent to the queue) the answer (or some other post posted by the same user) is upvoted and then the reputation of the person who posted it rises above 50 points. Will the answer still be sent to the Late Answers review queue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have seen answers in the Late Answers review queue by authors with just above 50 reputation; the review queue item was created before they had 50 reputation, and the items are not invalidated once the author crosses that threshold.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/30972290) is an example; the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70959021/timeline) shows the review item was created February 2nd, but I was able to review it just now, when the author had [61 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3932114/netkat?tab=reputation) (today's upvote is mine).

Comment: Confirmed in the question [here, and this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267080/282094) from Jon Ericson - 61 is possible for entry, and once in the queue some people have over 100 from other incoming upvotes before that review is seen.