# Why did the late answer queue spike on Sep 29, 2015?

Tags: discussion, review, late-answers

The late answer queue just went to 1.2k on Mathematics. On other sites the same happened (EL&U 850, SO 1.5k, TeX-LaTeX 500).   Why did this happen?

According to a comment on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150080/why-does-the-late-answer-review-queue-sometimes-spike-in-size-by-over-5000), there are no old late answers left over since begin 2013:

> No, the "minimum creation date" is being automatically gradually shifted back in time. In ~2 months, the Late Answers queue will cover all of Stack Overflow (first post on 2008-07-31!). –  Emmett Dec 26 '12 at 23:30

Did the definition of late answer somehow change?

Comment: The number is about 500 at [tex.se]. Note that the queues are typically empty at our site.

Comment: Because [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue).

Comment: @DanielFischer You should add that as an answer.

Comment: Over on Arqade, the Late Answers queue spiked to 1.8k.

Comment: @DanielFischer However, it does not explain why years old posts made in in the queue if only at most a month old one should have made it. These would be like 10 at [tex.se], not 500.

Comment: @yo' If you ever wrote some code, you should know the phenomenon that what you wrote is not always what you intended to write. I guess it's just a glitch in the implementation.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yep, you seem to be right. Jon Ericson [confessed it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue#comment866404_267080)

Comment: @yo' That's pretty much how the Late Answers queue works. It measures (1) the time span between the question and answer being posted, and (2) the _current_ reputation of the answerer. If the requirements on both are satisfied (and the answer hasn't gone through the LA queue before), the answer is enqueued. (See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222413).) So what happened is that hundreds of answers suddenly satisfied both conditions for the first time.

Comment: This seems counterproductive to me. If all these new "Late" answers were fine (or at least, not particularly noteworthy) before, why should they suddenly need reviewing now? And I'm not sure this question is a duplicate. This question is questioning the application of the new policy which the "duplicate" asked for.

Comment: You should all be happy with your tiny hills of reviews - [Ask Ubuntu spiked up to 4400!](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14469/367990)